# how I put image on progress bar?

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, wpf-4.0

i put progress bar but its not look proper

```
<ProgressBar Height="30" Width="300"  VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#0A8098" BorderBrush="Transparent"  Name="pbProcessing" >
                    <ProgressBar.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/ProgressBackground.png"/>
                    </ProgressBar.Background>
                    <ProgressBar.Clip>
                        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="20.5" RadiusY="20.5" Rect="0,0,300,19"/>
                    </ProgressBar.Clip>
                </ProgressBar>
```

but i shown 
[image: progress bar]

Any idea how to put image on progress bar perfrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ProgressBar Value="30" Height="30" Width="300"  VerticalAlignment="Center"    BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#0A8098" BorderBrush="Transparent"  Name="pbProcessing" >
        <ProgressBar.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="PART_Track" Source="bird1.jpg"  Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator"   
                        Fill="BlanchedAlmond"    
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ProgressBar.Template>
    </ProgressBar>
```